# Is it possible to verify method return types using the Boost concept check library?

Tags: c++, boost, c++-concepts

I've started using the [Boost concept check library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm). However, after reading the documentation, I don't seem to find a way to verify that a method in the concept returns a certain type. However, I don't see anything that says that this isn't possible, either, which is odd.

So, is it possible to write a concept that would fail if a return type wasn't correct?

Comment: could you go into more detail? Should this thing also fail if the return type can be converted to the certain type?

Comment: A return type of what exactly? What do you want to check with this concept?

Comment: @jrok The return type of a method, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Alex I suppose that an example of both would be nice. I didn't consider the question about conversion, but that was secondary to first finding out if anything along these lines was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double pi(){
    return 3.1415;
}

int main(){
    int int_pi{pi()};
}
```

When initializing variable using `{}` requies conversion leading to loss of information, it's compile error.

Alternatively:

```
#include <type_traits>
int main(){
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(pi()), double>::value, "pi() must return double");
}
```

I think the second code doesn't need any comment.